# How to align image to the bottom in a div inside td

Tags: html, css, image

I have designed a two column display using table.

I want to align image to the bottom inside `td`. I used `vertical-align: top` property in `td` to show the text from top but here is another problem, I want to show image with the text as well but sometimes when text get larger then some `td` boxes looks larger than another `td` boxes, I want to show equal `td` boxes.

There is free space in bottom of some `td` boxes, I think if I show the image from bottom then free space will shift from bottom to mid so these boxes will look attractive.

I do not want to show the image from top but bottom for that purpose i used another div for the image inside `td` but all in vain.

Note:- I have tried different positions properties like relative, absolute but none of them working (and sorry for my English).

```
$rows = $result->num_rows;    // Find total rows returned by database
if($rows > 0) {                          
  //if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row



$cols = 2;    // Define number of columns
$counter = 1;     //

$nbsp = $cols - ($rows % $cols);    // Calculate t




  echo '<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="4" 
 cellspacing="10" border= 1px solid white>';



while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


    $ads = $row['ads_id'];
     $id = $row['user_id'];


    if(($counter % $cols) == 1) {    // Check if it's new row
 echo '<tr>'; 
 }



 echo "<td>";



echo "<a href='welcome.php?user_id=$id&&ads_id=$ads'>";
   echo "Book title - ". $row["title"] ."<br>";

   echo "Book author - " . $row["author"] . "<br>";


   echo "Price -  " . $row["price"]. "<br>";

   echo "Grade - " . $row["grade"]. "<br>";
   echo "Description - " . $row["descrip"]. "<br>";

  $img = $row['pic'];
  echo "<div class=csc>";

  echo '<img src="'.$img.'">';

   echo"</div>";
  echo "</a>";    



echo "</td>"; 
  if(($counter % $cols) == 0) { 
  echo "</tr>";
  }
  $counter++; 
          //echo "</table>";



}






if($nbsp > 0) { // Add unused column in last row
        for ($i = 0; $i < $nbsp; $i++)  { 
            echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';     
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
            echo '</table>';

             } else {

   echo "0 results"; 

    }
    $conn->close();

     ?>
```

This is the CSS part

```
   table {

   width: 100%;
   text-align:center; 
   }


   th, td {
     vertical-align: top;
   text-align: left;
   padding: 8px;
   background: #D9E4F5;
   width: 50%;

   font-family: georgia;

   .csc{
   bottom:1000px;                          

   }
   .csc img{
    display: inline-block;

    width: 100%;

    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 100px;

    bottom:2000px;

    }
```

Comment: Hi zahid! I have a suggestion for making your question easier for someone here to answer. If you post the HTML output instead of your PHP script, it would be easier for someone to spot the problem you're having.

Comment: Hey I am sorry about my question I will edit it soon. It's work like <table>    <tr>     <td>  text+image  </td >     </tr>      </table>

Comment: Is there any possibility to move the text at upper part and  image at lower inside a single td tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you've missed a `}` in your css.

This may solve your problem:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center; 
}

th, td {
    vertical-align: bottom; /* This is what you need */

    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #D9E4F5;
    width: 50%;
    font-family: georgia;
}

.csc{
    bottom: 1000px;                          
}

.csc img{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    bottom: 2000px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hossein Zare the image is at perfect position now but some of td boxes text is now showing from top and some td boxes showing text from bottom, Please any solution to show text from top in all td boxes ?

Comment: If it's possible, add the table which is hardcoded (not php) to the question, i mean page source.

Comment: I am really sorry, I did not understand clearly, what do you really mean please ?

Comment: Copy and paste the html code. You can easily do it by Ctrl+U on Chrome, or Right click and click View page source, the table part is enough. <table> ... </table>.

Comment: Ok i will obviously do if it solves my problem, Thanks a lot dear , You are really nice.

Comment: But as you can see i have no further code for this design, I have used a loop to generate two td columns like $cols = 2; in my above code. I have no further html for this design.